# Explicit solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the nonlinear ODE
$$y'(t)=\frac{a(t)+b(t)}{a(t)b(t)}b(y(t)), \qquad y(0)=0, \qquad 0<t<1,$$
where $a,b \in C^0([0,1])$ are positive and Lipschitz.
Can I find $y$ explicitly in terms of $a,b$ ?

If $b(t)=b$ is constant, then obviously $y(t)=t+b\int_0^t \frac{1}{a(s)} \, ds$. What about the general case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as
$$
\int\frac{dy}{b(y)}=\int\left(\frac{1}{a(t)}+\frac{1}{b(t)}\right)dt
$$
so if you know the primitives of $1/a,1/b$ you can obtain the solution.

Comment: Nice observation ! Many thanks.